# Get Reactive Form Values In One Go

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, data-retrieval

I created a `Angular` project where user can give inputs and validate forms as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" formControlName="name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
          Name is required.
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="address" formControlName="address" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['address'].invalid && (angForm.controls['address'].dirty || angForm.controls['address'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['address'].errors.required">
          email is required.
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" (click)="buttonClicked()" class="btn btn-success">
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```

So as this is a reactive form, I tried to retrieve the values from the inputs as follows, assigned **ngModel** property in the text fields:

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" formControlName="name" type="text" />
```

In the `TypeScript`, I am doing something as follows:

```
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
       this.validateForm();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    } 

    angForm: FormGroup;
    name: string;
    address: string;

    //Retrieve value from input field on button click
    buttonClicked() {
       alert("Button works with the value: " + this.name);
    }
}
```

This works cool and I am getting the result as expected. But I've a model that has lot of properties. Say as an example:

```
export class SampleClass {
   name: string;
   address: string;
   ................
   With other lot of fields
}
```

So my question is can I do something like this if I've the same model properties in the **ngModel** defined in the frontend, so is it valid or could be possible to define as follows:

```
this.SampleClass = this.angForm.value; //So all properties can be retrieved in one go
```

Right now, what I am doing is binding all properties one by one as follows:

```
obj: SampleClass ;

this.obj = new SampleClass();
this.obj.name= this.name;
this.obj.address= this.address;
```

Comment: If you are using reactive forms you don't use `ngModel`. The form group (angForm) will have all the values in it. Read this!!: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the reactive form, which means you shouldn't use ngmodel you can retrive form's value using **getRawValue()** method.

Check this [angular guide on how to create a reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)